# Find empty array indexes function

Tags: php, arrays

I am checking array values empty or not like following:

Long format:

```
$empty = array();
foreach($array as $value)
   if(empty($value)) $empty[] = $value;
```

Expected Function:

```
$empty = array_empty_values($array);
```

Is there any function like `array_empty_values()` that find empty array indexes?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check and remove the empty array element you can check this function in php [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

**array_filter** accepts an array as input and removes all elements which are equal to **null / 0 / flase**

Comment: Ah, just read the question and the answer is: OP don't want to remove the empty values he wants it in a array

Comment: Oops! My bad :D sorry. then we can use `$result_array = array_diff($input, array_filter($input));` this snippet to get what he tries to get.

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) php built-in function

```
function filter_empty($var) {
  return empty($var);
}

$result_array = array_filter($your_array, "filter_empty");
```

---

```
$your_array = array(1,'2','3',false,'');
$result_array = array_filter($your_array, "filter_empty");
echo print_r($result_array, true);
```

will print

```
Array
(
    [3] =>
    [4] =>
)
```

If you need only indexes you can use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) built-in function

```
echo print_r(array_keys($result_array), true);
```

that will print

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
)
```

Comment: @Rizier123: Nope, is the opposite :)

Comment: Sorry, just saw it :D (BTW: This works too: `$result_array = array_diff($arr, array_filter($arr));`) Then OP don't has to write a extra function

Comment: @Rizier123: yes, it's a valid alternative

Answer (score 0):

You need an array with the keys, not with the values. because the values are empty.

```
/**
 * Get keys of empty array values
 * @param array $array The array to check.
 * @return array The keys of the empty values. 
 */
array_empty_values($array) {
    $empty = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
       if(empty($value)) {
           $empty[] = $key;
       }
    }
    return $empty;
}
```